# How can I use HTML tags in a Laravel localization file?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-localization

I'm trying to utilize Laravel's localization feature, but I need to be able to put emphasis or bolden a portion of a phrase. Inserting a HTML tag into the language file causes it to be escaped when outputted to a blade.

For example, here is my language file entry:

```
return [
    'nav' => [
        'find' => '<strong>Find</strong> Your Home',
    ]
];
```

When I call it from within a blade: *(I've tried using triple braces as well.)*

```
{{ trans('base.nav.find') }}
```

It outputs:

```
&lt;strong&gt;Find&lt;/strong&gt; Your Home
```

---

I could potentially split the phrasing up like:

```
return [
    'nav' => [
        'fyh' => [
            'find' => 'Find',
            'yh'   => 'Your Home',
        ]
    ]
]
```

And then output:

```
<strong>{{ trans('base.nav.fyh.find') }}</strong>{{ trans('base.nav.fyh.yh') }}
```

But that seems like overkill. Any better solutions?

Comment: The second option isn't just overkill, it's broken. What's a translator supposed to do if in their language the verb goes at the end of the sentence? You can place translated strings close to each other on a page, but you generally don't want to concatenate them to form sentences or paragraphs.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Use `{!! !!}` instead of `{{ }}` to prevent escaping:

```
{!! trans('nav.find') !!}
```

Comment: Ahh, damn! I'm not sure how I overlooked that. Thank you. I will accept the answer when SO allows me to.

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen You mentioned triple braces, so I just wanted to mention that his is one of the changes between L4 and L5. In L4, `{{ }}` was unescaped and `{{{ }}}` was escaped. In L5, `{!! !!}` is unescaped and `{{ }}` is escaped.

Comment: Thanks, my last stint with Laravel was version 4, so I missed that change now that I'm working with a clean install of 5.1

Comment: Be aware that the unescaped approach can lead to vulnerabilites like XSS if the attacker can somehow write to /lang

Answer (score 11):

Using `@lang` directive:

```
@lang('nav.find')
```

Source: [Retrieving Translation Strings](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/localization#retrieving-translation-strings)

Comment: This @lang directive is not helping with span markup when used for 'placeholder'

Answer (score 8):

Using Laravel 5.6 and above, can use the `__` helper along with the blade syntax:

`{!! __('pagination.next') !!}`

Had to do those for the pagination blade templates.