# Laravel raw expression query localization (v 5.6)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, laravel-5

I am using laravel (5.6) raw expression query and doing morris donut chart with this. My web site has localization support. Every field working fine which are comes from language PHP files. But these data i mean coming from MySQL for morris chart is native language. I couldn't make them multi-language supported.

```
class DashboardController extends Controller {
    public function Index() {

        $emlakCounts = DB::table('emlaks')
            ->join('property_types', 'property_types.id', '=', 'emlaks.property_type_id')
            ->select(DB::raw('property_types.title as label'), DB::raw('count(*) as value'))
            ->groupBy('label')
            ->get();

        $otomobilsCounts = DB::table('otomobils')
            ->join('vehicle_types', 'vehicle_types.id', '=', 'otomobils.vehicle_type_id')
            ->select(DB::raw('vehicle_types.title as label'), DB::raw('count(*) as value'))
            ->groupBy('label')
            ->get();

        return view('admin.dashboard', [
            'total_emlaks'      => DB::table('emlaks')->count(),
            'total_otomobils'   => DB::table('otomobils')->count(),
            'total_members'     => DB::table('users')->count(),
            'total_messages'    => DB::table('messages')->count(),
            'emlakCounts'       => $emlakCounts,
            'otomobilsCounts'   => $otomobilsCounts
        ]);
    }
}
```

and this is output

```
[{"label":"House","value":1},{"label":"Land","value":1}]
```

(property_types is coming from mysql). I must make labels multilanguage supported but i don't know what should i do.

```
{{ __('langfile.' . $property_types)}}
```

this is not working.

Comment: You haven't declared `$property_types` and still pass it `{{ __('langfile.' . $property_types)}}` here.

Comment: Under the property_types mysql table row (ID, Title, Slug) there are 4 types of property types listing. 

These are Title Row andI did exact declaration like;
```
'Land' => 'example',
'Building' => 'example',
'House' => 'example',
'Commercial' => 'example',

```
What is wrong ?

Comment: Check this [How can I use HTML tags in a Laravel localization file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30810776/how-can-i-use-html-tags-in-a-laravel-localization-file). i hope it helps

Comment: I still couldn't fix it. It did not work for me.