# Add Html Tag in Laravel

Tags: html, laravel

i'm write a html tag in a lang file

```
'resend' => 'Your account is not confirmed. Please click the confirmation link in your e-mail, or <a href=":url">click here</a> to resend the confirmation e-mail.',
```

But it does not display well on the output :[image](https://screenshots.firefox.com/WEQzcvKw2RXmBaIS/127.0.0.1)

How do I put the html tag inside {!! !!}?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use HTML tags in a Laravel localization file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30810776/how-can-i-use-html-tags-in-a-laravel-localization-file)

Answer (score 0):

You should use it like this: `{{ __('messages.welcome') }}`

You can read more about localization on this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/localization#introduction)

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to save such messages in a variable in Language folder. It provides you way to re-use these messages without writing them again and again.

Suppose, you have a message "Success! You data is inserted". and this message is used multiple times in your project. Now, if a condition comes that you need to change this message to "Success" only, then you have to change it all over your project.

Go to language *folder->english->somefile.php*

**'welcome_msg' => 'Success! You data is inserted'**

and fetch this 'welcome_msg' key into your view.